# Pass one variable from tpl child to parent tpl in smarty

Tags: php, variables, parameter-passing, smarty, facebook-opengraph

I try to correctly add an og:image from open graph to my website which uses smarty templates.
I correctly insert other og:tags in the  section, but in image tag I must use variable called $image.file_name. 
Unfortunately that tag is only avaible in child tpl file called link_summary.tpl which is called in main template in  section.

This causes errors in facebook sharing debugger:

> Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be
>   because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
>   Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

I want to ask, is there a way to pass just that one variable from child.tpl to parent.tpl? When I'm trying to include that variable from child it insert the whole child content in  instead of that one variable.

main/parent.tpl file og:meta tags looks:

```
  <!--OG types-->
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1069177856507061" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://hotter.pl{$story_url}" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{$posttitle} | Hotter" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pl_PL" />
    {if $meta_description neq ""}
    <meta property="og:description" content="{$meta_description|truncate:'300'}" />
    {/if}
    <!-- /OG types-->
```

That one og:image tag from link_summary(child).tpl looks:

```
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_kliqqi_story_end"}
<meta property="og:image" content="http://hotter.pl/modules/upload/attachments/thumbs/{$image.file_name|substr:0:-12}600x6000.jpg" />
<!--/link_summary.tpl -->
```

I want to move og:image tag to parent but {$image.file_name} variable need to be passed.

Thanks in advance for tips.

Answer (score 1):

Per default new or changed variable inside included templates have local scope and are not visible inside the including / parent template, but you can determine the scope yourself.

Have a look into the [Smarty manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl):

> This default behaviour can be changed for all variables assigned in
>   the included template by using the scope attribute at the `{include}`
>   statement or for individual variables by using the scope attribute at
>   the [`{assign}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) statement. The later is useful to return values
>   from the included template to the including template.

Here's a short example how this can be done using [`{assign}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl), since this should fit your purpose :

---

### `parent.tpl`:

```
{include file="child.tpl"}

{* display variable from child template *}
{$var}
```

---

### `child.tpl`:

```
{assign var="var" value="hello world" scope=parent}
```